# How to get yaml-pipeline demands?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

How to get the demands of a pipeline created from a yaml-file? The yaml-file contains the demands:

```
...
jobs:
- job: my_job
  displayName: My Job
  pool:
    name: my_pool
    demands:
    - Agent.Name -equals My-Agent-1
  step:
...
```

If the pipeline is created through the user interface, then I can get the demands using the [get-request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). The response body will contain the demands.
[image]

But if I usually use the [get-request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) for a yaml-pipeline, then the response body will not contain the demands! Do I need to parse the yaml-file myself?!

Unfortunately, I did not find an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST API [Definitions - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) doesn't support get the definitions inside the YAML. You need to parse the yaml-file yourself.

Comment: How to find agents for the pipeline? Azure understands the demands of the yaml-pipeline. Is it possible to determine their compatibility by the agent id and the pipeline id?

Comment: I created a separate topic for discussion: [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74276623/how-to-check-the-ability-to-run-pipeline-on-an-agent)