# How to check the ability to run pipeline on an agent?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have agents pool that have different user capabilities (user paremeters). Also I have pipelines which contain different demands for agents. In other words, it is not possible to run pipeline in all agents.

How to find out which agents are suitable for running the pipeline?

How to check the possibility of running a pipeline on an agent?

---

I can get data (contains capabilities/paremeters) about agents using query:     `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{poolId}/agents?includeCapabilities=true`

I can find out the data (demands) of manual-pipelines (pipelines created manually by users) using query:
`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}`

But how to get the requirements of pipelines created using yaml files?

Unfortunately, I did not find an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Demands and capabilities are designed for use with self-hosted agents so that jobs can be matched with an agent that meets the requirements of the job.
Please see the doc for more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

So, when you set demands for the pipelines, it will automatically check and be assigned to a suitable agent randomly.

But if for some reasons you want to see the list of agents.

Then please see the following idea to help to get the suitable agents for a pipeline.
1.Use the rest api `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}` to get the demands of the manual pipeline.
Here if I set it as

```
 demands:
  - user1
  - user2
```

2.Use the rest api 'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{poolId}/agents?includeCapabilities=true&demands=user2,user1&api-version=6.0'to get agents that is suitable for the pieline run.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW97Q.png)

But if it is not your issue, please kindly clarify and if you could explain the purpose of doing so, that would be good.

Thanks

Comment: Hi! You repeated what I wrote in the first post. This works, but only for pipelines created manually by the user (using the web interface). But how do I get the "demands" of a pipeline created from a yaml file?

Pipeline created with yaml file does not return "demands" (_https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}_).

Comment: Hi, have you tried to use the rest api(dev.azure.com{org-name}/{Project-name}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}) to get the repo id and yaml file name then use them to get the full yaml definition by using the rest api(dev.azure.com{org-name}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoriesId}/Items?path=/{yaml-file-name}.yml&api-version=7.1-preview.1), then you could find the 'demands' in the response value. Is it what you want?

Comment: Hi @GranmaSquid3, will appreciate if you could tell the latest information about the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps:

1. Get the yaml file name with the rest API: `https://dev.azure.com/{org-name}/{Project-name}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}`
2. Get the yaml file content using the name we get from last step: `https://dev.azure.com/{org-name}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoriesId}/Items?path=/{yaml-file-name}.yml&api-version=7.1-preview.1`

The result should be the whole content of the YAML file, you can see the demands in the file content.